# Keep values in create form after Save and Add in flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

In my application it would be useful to keep the submitted values in the create form after clicking "Save and Add'. Very often only a few values are changed in the following "Save and Add" operations. What would be the best way to accomplish this in Flask-Admin ?